# Strip left/right a string (and chomp)

Tags: haskell

I have found nothing about how to strip a string (remove leading/trailing characters) in Haskell, and there’s no place place to find such a `strip` or `chomp` function (correct me if I’m wrong).

What am I gonna do?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/1.0.0/doc/html/Data-String-Utils.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [`Data.Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text.html). Anything that uses Prelude lists, such as `String`s, usually performs poorly, especially with functions like `stripR`. Some consider it a mistake from the past, because it has infected a lot of (otherwise sensible) interfaces with the inefficiencies of using singly linked lists of characters (`String`) for textual data.

The functions you're looking for are, in order: `dropWhile`, `dropWhileEnd`, `dropAround`, `stripStart`, `stripEnd`, `strip`.

Note that there's no specific function for stripping based on character equality. You don't really gain anything from aliasing `dropX` with a predicate, unless it's a *very* commonly used one like `Data.Char.isSpace`.

Answer (score 5):

First off, you should use `Text` (from the `text` package) instead of `String`, since `text` is much more efficient.

Also, `text` already has this function:

```
-- Remove leading and trailing white space from a string.
strip :: Text -> Text
```

Answer (score 3):

The more general approach would be to pass a predicate to the `strip` functions, so one could `stripL isSpace` e.g. to remove all leading white space.

Then `stripL` would however just be an alias for `dropWhile`.

For the stripping of the end, a potentially more efficient version uses `foldr`,

```
stripR :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
stripR pred = foldr keepOrDrop []
  where
    keepOrDrop c xs
        | pred c    = case xs of
                        [] -> []
                        _  -> c:xs
        | otherwise = c:xs
```

that can start producing output without traversing the entire input list, and is efficient if there are no long runs of elements satisfying the predicate it the input.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 functions and 3 currified aliased functions to make it through:

```
stripL :: Char -> String -> String
stripL x = dropWhile (==x)

stripR :: Char -> String -> String
stripR x = reverse . stripL . reverse

strip :: Char -> String -> String
strip x = stripL x . stripR x

chompL :: String -> String
chompL = stripL ' '

chompR :: String -> String
chompR = stripR ' '

chomp :: String -> String
chomp = strip ' '
```

What do you think? Is it possible to add such functions to `Data.String`?

Comment: `stripR x = reverse . stripL . reverse`

Comment: Good definitions, however, I would argue that if you're using String, you should try to process your input linearly, and only ever strip whitespace at the front, using  dropWhile isSpace to cover tabs etc, because stripping at the back of a list is inefficient. (If you strip and you got [], you're at the end of your input.) Hence I would only ever use stripL and find dropWhile more conveniently flexible. This may be why they were omitted.